# Facing some visual erros?

Tags: launcher, calendar

I suddenly saw some unexpected changes in my ubuntu 20.04.2. i have not made any changes like this. screen shot attached. all the icon of app drawer became small and the calendar visual have changed to some pathetic style. Please look into this help me to resolve this issue as i don't want to format and reinstall OS again.

Attaching screenshot1 [Calendar issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5iIU.jpg).

Attaching screenshot 2 [app drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N9jV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To debug such issues

1. Disable any custom theme and switch to a default one. You can do so using Tweaks, on the "Appearance" tab. Tweaks is not installed by default, but can be installed with the command `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`.

If the issue persists, then you may need to log out and back in to resolve it. Do that first before going on.

2. If that does not resolve the issue, then disable all custom extensions, and reenable them one by one. Also there, you can use Tweaks ("Extensions" tab). On more recent Ubuntu versions, you can use the tools "Tweaks", not installed by default (`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs`.

This will allow you to see what causes the display issues, your custom theme or one (or a combination of) custom extensions. You then can work around (use a different theme or discontinue using an extension, etc.)